# Typescript type guard removes null or undefined union-types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an object literal and want to write a type guard for the type of that specific object.

My object looks as follows:

```
const typeDictator = {
    value: undefined as number | undefined | string,
}
```

so if I'm not mistaken the type for my object should result in

```
{value: number | undefined | string}
```

but whenever I write a type guard for it like this:

```
function generic<T>(obj: unknown, type: T): obj is T {
    return true;
}
```

and check the type with

```
const typedObject = null;

if(generic(typedObject, typeDictator)) {
    typedObject
}
```

then the type of `typedObject` is reduced to `{value: number | string}`.

But why does it remove the `undefined` or `null` union-types and does it change anything relevant?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://tsplay.dev/Lw6oeN). I see it reduced to `never`, since there is no overlap between `null` and `typeof typeDictator`.  Please make sure your code constitutes a [mcve] so everyone's on the same page.

Comment: Indeed. Using null here is problematic. Try again with `const typedObject = {}`, for instance.

Comment: @spender it results in the same behaviour: https://i.imgur.com/4ovs3qC.png I'm starting to think that's simply an error of my IDE PhpStorm.

Comment: Yep. It's my IDE. It works on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgEQJbCgQyiATjALwwDeAsAFAw0wBu2ANgK7IBcMYzjjM2EnZgFsARskIAfGNHzowAcxhSuPADRUAvlSoIU0kEOQAVJMmJxTIAGYWUGLLgIBubZSvMwWdOBjzkYcUwAHiMAPgAKEBEAKw4PAGswEAB3MFVbdhgjAEoOKOiYdAEjMipaGHxkKGZ8MDh8VhdKLUoqUEhYXWQAEwB5GOQscxVGJqp0K3C-ANlgcK6+gax0rvscPHxs7NLqWlXMdYJNIA) @jcalz If I hover typedObject it says: https://i.imgur.com/Ndfxem1.png but in PhpStorm it says https://i.imgur.com/4ovs3qC.png That's where the error is at.

Comment: Possibly you are on an older TS version?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"strict": true,` to your tsconfig. If your tsconfig is too permissive (or missing altogether), then null and undefined will be removed from types.